# How to change the length of a django form field

Tags: css, django

I have a django form and I want to increase the length of a field

**html**

```
<td class='email_field'><span class='email_field'>{{ signup_form.email }}</span></td>
```

**css**

```
.email_field{
    width: 350px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The background is coloured for 350px, but the field remains at the standard width (180px)
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is in *forms.py*

**forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
        widgets = {'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 40}),}
```